# How to collect the value directly from a stream -> filter of a list?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

Given is a list of Strings that needs to be filtered. I know that the result is always one String. I want to get this value. Is there a better solution than doing this

```
List<String> bla = new ArrayList();
bla
 .stream()
 .filter(s->s.equals("something"))
 .collect(Collectors.toList())
 .get(0);
```

Something like getOrDefault would be awesome.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `findFirst()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--

Comment: With this specific predicate, you may simply use `String result = bla.contains("something")? "something": defaultValue;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--).

But since you're sure that there will be only 1 element in the list that you're searching for, then you can use [`.findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) or [`.findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) which returns an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

You can then get your object by simply calling [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) of this `Optional` class.

```
List<String> bla = new ArrayList();

String bla2 = bla
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.equals("something"))
    .findAny()
    .get();

System.out.println(bla2);
```

---

**Example**

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List < String > bla = new ArrayList();
        bla.add("one");
        bla.add("something");
        bla.add("two");

        String bla2 = bla
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> s.equals("something"))
            .findAny()
            .get();

        System.out.println(bla2);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
something
```

Comment: Or `findAny()`. Also, to be consistent with code in question, move the `get()` call to the method chain.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `findFirst` which returns `Optional` object and **then use `Optional.orElseGet` to set your default value**.

```
Optional<String> optString = bla.stream()
         .filter(s->s.equals("something")).findFirst();

String somethingValue = optString.orElseGet(() -> "DEFAULT_VALUE");
```

Also, I strongly suggest, **not to directly invoke the `get()`** method as it will throw `NoSuchElementException`, look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) for details, but you can use `orElseGet` as shown above.

Comment: Why waste time/resources collecting to list, just to re-stream it? Just call `findFirst()` right after `filter()`.

Comment: thanks, I got your point, exactly right, there is no need to re-stream, updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than using

`bla.stream()
 .filter(s->s.equals("something"))
 .collect(Collectors.toList())
 .get(0);`

You can use the following

`bla
 .stream()
 .filter(s->s.equals("something"))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());`

`get(0)` is not required

Comment: If you want only first found record you can use @javaguy method